# Find the intervals on which f is increasing or decreasing where $f(x) =\frac{ x ^2}{x^2+3} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I have calculated the critical point at $0$ and that the function is increasing on both left and right of $0$. But, I don't know how to show my work that the function is approaching to 1 for + infinity and - infinity.

Comment: Presumably, you mean $x^2/(x^2 +3),$ not $(x^2/x^2)+3.$

Comment: Both the numerator $x^2$ and the denominator $x^2+3$ are non-negative, so $x^2/(x^2+3)$ can't approach a negative number when $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: Hint: with polynomial division you can modify your fraction to something easier to work with

Comment: A standard way is to divide both the numerator and denominator by $x^2$, then treat $\frac3{x^2}$ in the new denominator as $0$ as $x$ approaches either infinity.

Comment: thanks @peterwhy

Comment: By the way, how did you find that the function is increasing on the left of $0$? $f(0)=0$, and $f(x)$ for negative $x$ can't be below $0$.

Comment: @peterwhy but even that gives -ev number for left side so still finding a way.. but if i put the numbers in $f(x)$ instead of derivative that might work

Comment: @peterwhy that question got me thinking because i was substituting these values in $f(x)$ not in the derivative. so let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you try a few negative $x$ in $f(x)$, for example $f(-1) = 1/4$, then comparing with $f(0)=0$, that already means $f$ is decreasing somewhere between $-1<x<0$ and is not always increasing.

Comment: By the first derivative $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

$$f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{x^2 + 3}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{6 x}{\left(x^2+3\right)^2}$$

The only critical point is at $x = 0$ for which $f(0) = 0$ hence $P = (0, 0)$.

By the study of the sign of $f'(x)$ we can conclude that the function is increasing for $x > 0$ and decreasing for $x < 0$ since all we have to look at is the numerator (the denominator is always positive).

To show the horizontal asymptotes, just take the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{x^2}{x^2 + 3} = \dfrac{x^2}{x^2\left(1 + \dfrac{3}{x^2}\right)} = \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{3}{x^2}} \to 1$$

The same holds when $x\to -\infty$

[image]

Comment: If you see the graph the function is increasing on the interval x< 0 as well.

Comment: @Xeeshan_65 The graph has to be read from left to right.

Comment: Oh thanks how dumb i am. sorry!

Comment: @Xeeshan_65 Nah, don't worry! What matters is that you got it! :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution without derivatives: first, notice that $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+3}$ is even since $f(-x)=f(x)$. So, it is enough to study the monotonicity on $[0,\infty)$.

Then, notice that $\frac{x^2}{x^2+3}=\frac{x^2+3-3}{x^2+3}=1-\frac{3}{x^2+3}$ and observe that:

(i) the composition of an increasing function and a decreasing function is a decreasing function;

(ii) if $g$ is a monotonic function, then for $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ the function $a \cdot g$ preserve its monotonicity if $a>0$, invert its monotonicity if $a<0$.

(iii) the sum two decreasing functions is a decreasing function.

So, since $1/t$ is decreasing separately on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ and since $x^2+3$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, it follows from (i) that the composition $\frac{1}{x^2+3}$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$. So, from (ii), it follows that $-\frac{3}{x^2+3}$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. Finally, since constant functions are both increasing and decreasing, from (iii) it follows that $1-\frac{3}{x^2+3}$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. So $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and hence, since its even, it is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ and decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$.